# IQueryable command timeout

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I have one problem. I'm using Linq and IQueryable interface to work with my database.
That is my code:

```
public static List<Stat> GetStateList(DataClassesDataContext db, int pageNumber,
    int pageSize, DateTime beginTime, DateTime endTime,
    Dictionary<GetSourcesNameResult, bool> sourceDictionary,
    bool[] WarnLevel, ref int count)
{
    IQueryable<Stat> result = db.Stats;

    result = DateFilter(result, beginTime, endTime);
    result = DictionaryFilter(result, sourceDictionary);
    result = ErrorFilter(result, WarnLevel);
    result = result.OrderBy(a => a.EventTime); //sort by eventTime

    count = result.Count();
    var resultList = result.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                           .Take(pageSize).ToList();

    return new List<Stat>(resultList);
}
```

In my database lots of elements. If my filters give me about 1mln elements. I have timeout exception in this:

```
count = result.Count();
```

What I need to do with this?
Sql expression:

```
SELECT [t0].[RecordId], [t0].[RecordTime], [t0].[EventGUID], 
       [t0].[AssociatedEventGUID], [t0].[EventId], [t0].[EventTime], 
       [t0].[WarnLevel], [t0].[UserType], [t0].[SourceId], 
       [t0].[FactoryNumber], [t0].[CntrlId], [t0].[CntrlFactoryNumber], 
       [t0].[ParamData], [t0].[TargetId], [t0].[SourceName], [t0].[TargetName]
FROM 
       [dbo].[Log] AS [t0]
WHERE 
   ((CONVERT(Int,[t0].[WarnLevel])) IN (@p0, @p1, @p2)) AND 
   ([t0].[SourceName] IN (@p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, 
   @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, 
   @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31, @p32, @p33, @p34, @p35, @p36, 
   @p37, @p38, @p39, @p40, @p41, @p42, @p43, @p44, @p45, @p46, @p47, @p48, 
   @p49, @p50, @p51, @p52, @p53, @p54, @p55, @p56, @p57, @p58, @p59, @p60, 
   @p61, @p62, @p63, @p64, @p65, @p66, @p67, @p68, @p69, @p70, @p71, @p72, 
   @p73, @p74, @p75, @p76, @p77, @p78, @p79, @p80, @p81, @p82, @p83, @p84, 
   @p85, @p86, @p87, @p88, @p89, @p90, @p91, @p92, @p93, @p94, @p95, @p96, 
   @p97, @p98, @p99, @p100, @p101, @p102, @p103, @p104, @p105, @p106, @p107, 
   @p108, @p109, @p110, @p111, @p112, @p113, @p114, @p115, @p116, @p117, 
   @p118, @p119, @p120, @p121, @p122, @p123, @p124, @p125, @p126, @p127, 
   @p128, @p129, @p130, @p131, @p132, @p133, @p134, @p135, @p136, @p137, 
   @p138, @p139, @p140, @p141, @p142, @p143, @p144, @p145, @p146, @p147, 
   @p148, @p149, @p150, @p151, @p152, @p153, @p154, @p155, @p156, @p157, 
   @p158, @p159, @p160, @p161, @p162, @p163, @p164, @p165, @p166, @p167, 
   @p168, @p169, @p170, @p171, @p172, @p173, @p174, @p175, @p176, @p177, 
   @p178, @p179, @p180, @p181, @p182, @p183, @p184, @p185, @p186, @p187, 
   @p188, @p189, @p190, @p191, @p192, @p193, @p194, @p195, @p196, @p197, 
   @p198, @p199, @p200, @p201, @p202, @p203, @p204, @p205, @p206, @p207, 
   @p208, @p209, @p210, @p211, @p212, @p213, @p214, @p215, @p216)) 
  AND ([t0].[EventTime] >= @p217) AND ([t0].[EventTime] <= @p218)
    ORDER BY [t0].[EventTime]
```

Comment: You should have a look at the SQL generated by the linq statement.

Comment: @Magnus: added sql command.

Comment: I doubt that the `count` query would generate that, but anyway you should run the query and examine the execution plan. Perhaps you need some indexing of the tables.

Comment: @Magnus Ok, but this is sql request that creates from my filters. How I can set timeout for "count" function in sql?

Comment: Run the query and analyse the execution plan. There you can see why the query is taking so long and apply appropriate fix.

Comment: I would say column `SourceName` is a candidate for indexing.

Comment: You got about 2000 items in the second 'IN'... That's going to be slow. Try putting index on sourcename, if that doesn't help, maybe you have to break the list and do them separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the DataContext `CommandTimeout` Property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout.aspx

And out of curiosity, why do you have

```
var resultList = result.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                           .Take(pageSize).ToList();

    return new List<Stat>(resultList);
```

and not

```
List<Stat> resultList = result.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                           .Take(pageSize).ToList();

    return resultList ;
```